# Linux/ unix duplicate names

Tags: linux, sorting, unix, awk, uniq

What I need to do is, to check for duplicate domain names and find if there is some.
So far I tried many commands with grep, awk ,sort, uniq but couldn't work this out, I am feeling its very simple, but can't reach it.
P.s. If i use `uniq -c` I get a huge list of string in this file, and I see how many duplicates it has and which by number string it is.

adding 20 rows from the file I am using

```
1,google.com
2,facebook.com
3,youtube.com
4,yahoo.com
5,baidu.com
6,amazon.com
7,wikipedia.org
8,twitter.com
9,taobao.com
10,qq.com
11,google.co.in
12,live.com
13,sina.com.cn
14,weibo.com
15,linkedin.com
16,yahoo.co.jp
17,tmall.com
18,blogspot.com
19,ebay.com
20,hao123.com
```

The output I would like to see

```
>        2 google
>        2 yahoo
```

Thanks for help !

Comment: I tried that, but dont forget, there is like 100000 strings,
After i do    uniq -c, I just see  a HUGE list, which isn't helping

Comment: oh it does. how do duplicates look in that list? and how do unique elements?

Comment: ok, lets say duplicate would be 
1,google.com
2,google.co.in     and i supose there is more in those 100000 rows
and lets say unique would be
12,live.com

Comment: I was talking about the output of `uniq -c`. what you wrote clearly won't help to anybody. it's irrelevant.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a minimal example containing some duplicates and your desired output?

Comment: Edited main post, I hope that makes more sense now

Comment: @TomasŠiaudvytis and what would be the output for this given input? Make it more clear if you want to get help. Recommended reading: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like this to get the output you want:

```
$ awk -F'[.,]' '{++a[$2]}END{for(i in a)if(a[i]>1)print a[i],i}' file
2 google
2 yahoo
```

With the input field separator to either `.` or `,`, the first `{block}` is run for every row in the file. It builds up an array `a` using the second field: "google", "facebook", etc. `$2` is the value of the second field, so `++a[$2]` increments the value of the array `a["google"]`, `a["facebook"]`, etc. This means that the value in the array increases by one every time the same name is seen.

Once the whole file is processed, the `for (i in a)` loop runs through all of the keys in the array ("google", "facebook", etc.) and prints those whose value is greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Given this file:

```
$ cat /tmp/test.txt
1,google.com
2,facebook.com
3,youtube.com
4,yahoo.com
5,baidu.com
6,amazon.com
7,wikipedia.org
8,twitter.com
9,taobao.com
10,qq.com
11,google.co.in
12,live.com
13,sina.com.cn
14,weibo.com
15,linkedin.com
16,yahoo.co.jp
17,tmall.com
18,blogspot.com
19,ebay.com
20,hao123.com
```

In a Perl 1 liner:

```
$ perl -lane '$count{$1}++ if /^\d+,(\w+)/; END {while (($k, $v) = each %count) { print "$v $k" if $v>1}}' /tmp/test.txt 
2 yahoo
2 google
```